# How to write elasticsearch-sql query using Java High-Level REST Client API

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my Elasticsearch-sql query. I executed this query using Kibana and getting valid output.

GET _sql?format=json
{
  "query": "SELECT Count(appId) FROM eps_stbl_logs where cast(timestamp AS DATE) = TODAY() and status = 'COMPLETED'"
  }

This needs to be written in restHighLevelClient java API. Could you please help to write java API as I am new to ElasticSearch with Java.

Answer (score 3):

It could work like this:

```
        Request request = new Request("GET", "/_sql");
        request.setJsonEntity("{\"query\":\"SELECT Count(appId) FROM eps_stbl_logs where cast(timestamp AS DATE) = TODAY() and status = 'COMPLETED'\"}");
        Response response = restHighLevelClient.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: hank you Alexander :) I will try and get back toy you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working perfectly. I need one more suggestion from you for the below query. How can I add fitter query for existing java code.                                                                                                                                                                        GET _sql?format=json
{
    "query": "SELECT Count(appId) FROM eps_stbl_logs where status = 'COMPLETED'",
    "filter": {
        "range" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "from" : "10/05/2020",
            "to" : "13/05/2020",
            "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy"
}}}}

Comment: Just add the filter condition:
    String query = "{\"query\":\"SELECT * FROM eps_stbl_logs\","
                    + "\"filter\": {"
                    + "    \"range\": {"
                    + "       \"@timestamp\": {"
                    + "           \"from\": \"10/05/2020\","
                    + "                   \"to\": \"13/05/2020\","
                    + "                   \"format\": \"dd/MM/yyyy\""
                    + "       }"
                    + "   }"
                    + "}}";

Comment: Thanks a Alexander for your quick response. :)